# Event.preventDefault() is not working in click

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In the following code i am trying to use event.preventDefault() but it's not working. I am trying to fix an issue where if name is blank then its not clickable.

```
      <Anchor onClick={(event) => { props.someMethod(prop1, event); }}>
        <div className="u-pt--sm">
          {prop1.title}
        </div>
    .....
 </Anchor>

  someMethod(prop1, event) {
    if (prop1.name === '') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
   ....
  }
```

If i debug the code i see event is coming as

```
[[Handler]]
:
Object
[[Target]]
:
SyntheticMouseEvent
[[IsRevoked]]
:
false
```

Any idea why its not working?

Comment: that will get called when `prop1.name === ''`, just check the value of `prop1.name`.

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes i checked the prop1.name and it's blank but its still clickable

Comment: *but its still clickable* sorry didn't get this part, what do you mean by that.

Comment: so the item on the app should not be clickable if prop1.name is blank. prop1.name gets evaluated after a fetch so in that time i dont want the item to be clickable.

Comment: `preventDefault` prevents the default action of the event.  It won't prevent other code from running (like the `...` in your example).  It also won't disable the button.

Comment: by mean disabling you want to return from `someMethod` function.

Comment: Just put `if (prop1.name === '') {return; }` Next code wont be executed.

Comment: Thanks all for your comment. in this case its not clickable. trying to achieve something like this based on condition https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_preventdefault

Comment: @Nick.S. Can you show your `Anchor` component?

Answer (score 5):

for me the simple answer was to use `stopPropagation()` instead of `preventDefault()`

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('The link was clicked.')
}
```

called via:

```
 <IconButton onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}  >                                                              
   blah
 </IconButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access prop inside event function like below code snippet.

Also check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/maywmLm5/) (in jsfiddle) for preventDefault() functionality. 
Just check with changing the name prop. when name prop is not empty clicking on anchor tag will go to the new tab and try to open the URL otherwise it is disabled.

```js
var handleClick= function(event) {
     console.log(this.props.name);
     if (this.props.name === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
 }

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com" onClick={handleClick.bind(this)}>click me</a>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="name"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Note-

Need to explicitly bind the click event function with this. So inside event function, we can access props.

```
handleClick.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `event.preventDefault();` mechanism, you can conditionally set the event handler on the `onClick`.
In this simple example you have a `button` and a `checkbox`, the checkbox will be responsible on a property in the state called `clickable`.
Only if `clickable` is set to true we will pass an event handler to the `button` (we could of made it `disable` in the same way):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clickable: false
    };

    this.toggleClickable = this.toggleClickable.bind(this);
    this.onElementClick = this.onElementClick.bind(this);
  }

  toggleClickable() {
    this.setState({
      clickable: !this.state.clickable
    });
  }

  onElementClick(e) {
    console.log("element was clicked!");
  }

  render() {
    const { clickable } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="enableClick"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={clickable}
          onChange={this.toggleClickable}
        />
         <label htmlFor="enableClick">Enable clicks</label>
         <div/>
        <div className="button" onClick={clickable && this.onElementClick}>Click me if you can</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```